# git pull over https and port fails

Tags: git

curl can access the URL, but "git pull" can't. I guess there is something wrong with the URL handling of git if there is user+password+port in the url:

```
foo@workdevel123:~/src/foo$ git pull
error: The requested URL returned error: 503 while accessing https://user:password@example.com:40443/repos/djangotools/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

curl can access the page:

```
foo@workdevel123:~/src/foo$ curl https://user:password@example.com:40443/repos/djangotools/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
001d# service=git-upload-pack000000b525ceda9ef5cd8ef3542c3917c26229c4745d1342 HEADmulti_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed no-done agent=git/1.8.1.4
0040f22a42834c303630d0173ea0b232a9b486e92...
```

git version 1.8.1.4

Any change to pull with https, user+password and a different port?

Comment: how is the URL specified in git (`git remote -v`)? Also, what server is it?

Comment: 503 errors are usually temporary - try again later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with:

```
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1; git pull
```

There was an old proxy config in my ~/.gitconfig. Problem was between keyboard and chair.

The port number in the URL was not the problem.

Comment: NB: In BASH/DASH You don't need to export a shell variable if being passed to a command, e.g. GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git pull